# Trying to add nav drawer button to the app bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio-3.0

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#java)

I'm stuck at the bit where I'm trying to add the button to the app bar.

When I swipe right, the navigation drawer appears, so thats working.  Its just the button in the bar that I'm having problems with, When I add the `v7.widget.Toolbar` into the XML under FrameLayout it ruins the layout.

Orginally in my XML I just had a constraint layout, with a Scrollview as a child and inside that a LinearView (vertical).

However I cant get my head around why this isnt working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/seeds_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

When I run this the top bar just seems to overtake the entire window and the color disappears and the button is not clickable because the `LinearLayout` is over the top of it.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `FrameLayout` will overlap its child `View`s; i.e., it'll stack them one atop the other in the z-axis. Change the `FrameLayout` to a vertical `LinearLayout`, which will lay them out edge to edge. Also, your `NavigationView` needs to be listed last within the `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. I dont get why they would specifiy in the tutorial to use a framelayout?  ALso that works! But I've lost my toolbar colour, I'm guessing because i'm using my own toolbar now.

Comment: @MikeM. if you put that as an answer i'll mark it correct.

Comment: Yeah, they bungled that example. That's not surprising, sadly. Anyhoo, I'm good. :-) It's a common issue, and I'd probably just close this as a duplicate, if I had time to hunt one down. Feel free to post your adjusted layout in your own answer, if you like. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Btw, yeah, you'll need to set the background on the `Toolbar` yourself; e.g., `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

put `NavigationView` below `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, but that didnt fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Following on MikeM's comments above,  He said:

*FrameLayout will overlap its child Views; i.e., it'll stack them one atop the other in the z-axis. Change the FrameLayout to a vertical LinearLayout, which will lay them out edge to edge. Also, your NavigationView needs to be listed last within the DrawerLayout.*

So basically I had change my FrameLayout to Linearlayout and that worked.  Its a bit dissapointing that the Android documentation is like that but what I do.

Thanks, MikeM!